# Dialogflow weather webhook connection error

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, wsgi, dialogflow-es

[fullfillment page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmTv1.png)As for my personal interest i wanted to make a weather chatbot with the use of weather api.For that purpose i use dialogflow but when i do webhook connection as per the [Dialogflow github](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-python) but getting an error.
[intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBUjI.png),
[a single intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEMzc.png)
As per my api response generate this json

```
{
 "responseId": "e37136ba-270b-435d-bfd6-61d83e286d96",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "weather in delhi",
    "action": "weather",
    "parameters": {
      "address": {
        "city": "Delhi"
      },
      "unit": "",
      "date-time": "",
      "date-period": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/plunesweather-a4aa6/agent/sessions/4c9e41c9-a732-b2fd-f311-cdb0b03d8c3b/contexts/weather",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          "date-period": "",
          "address": {
            "city.object": {},
            "city.original": "delhi",
            "city": "Delhi"
          },
          "date-period.original": "",
          "unit": "",
          "unit.original": "",
          "address.original": "delhi",
          "date-time.original": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/plunesweather-a4aa6/agent/intents/f1b75ecb-a35f-4a26-88fb-5a8049b92b02",
      "displayName": "weather"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 538
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 13,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
  }
}
```

fullfillment request generate this json

```
{
  "responseId": "e37136ba-270b-435d-bfd6-61d83e286d96",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "weather in delhi",
    "action": "weather",
    "parameters": {
      "address": {
        "city": "Delhi"
      },
      "unit": "",
      "date-time": "",
      "date-period": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/plunesweather-a4aa6/agent/sessions/4c9e41c9-a732-b2fd-f311-cdb0b03d8c3b/contexts/weather",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          "date-period": "",
          "address": {
            "city.object": {},
            "city.original": "delhi",
            "city": "Delhi"
          },
          "date-period.original": "",
          "unit": "",
          "unit.original": "",
          "address.original": "delhi",
          "date-time.original": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/plunesweather-a4aa6/agent/intents/f1b75ecb-a35f-4a26-88fb-5a8049b92b02",
      "displayName": "weather"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 538
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 13,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
  }
}
```

Fulfillment response [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy8mr.png)
last few app logs shows error. As i am newbie i did't get how to remove these error.Thanks in advance.
[command line app logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yidJW.png)

EDIT : As i go to through stackdriver error reporting i find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWjlw.png)
looking for this problem i find  [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Comment: please show screenshots for intents and fulfillment settings along with weather service URL

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi i edit my question and you can check it. I use clear instruction provided by  https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-python

Comment: There is something wrong with your endpoint, `echo '{"queryResult": {"action": "weather"}}' | http POST https://weather-221005.appspot.com/` produces `HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`, can you include your App Engine logs?

Comment: @Dustin i edit my question and include app logs now it shows some error but don't know how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the example, you need to change this line in `forecast.py`:

```
-        furthest_date_requested = dt.combine(date_start,
-                                             timedelta(days=forecast_length))
+        furthest_date_requested = date_start + timedelta(days=forecast_length)
```

[This has been updated in the source repository,](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-python/commit/ab457240e3cfff5172f26658f27aa5bfe54e0eac) so you can also just pull that repo.

Comment: Thanks @Dustin but i already try this doesn't change anything .

Comment: From your logs, it looks like you tried changing `timedelta` to `time`, can you confirm that you actually tried the change I suggested instead?

Comment: Yes @Dustin i tried that and after that my problem with timedelta is remove but now now i am getting a unbound error. You can see my recent stack driver logs as i edit my question

Comment: Here you can see my https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWjlw.png very recent stackdriver error details. Thanks in advance